# Cooldown в python

Tags: python

Код

```
if text[0] == 'Бонус':
    print('Бонус выдан!')

if(если 5 минут не прошло):
    print('Подождите ещё чч:мм:сс')
else:
    print('бонус выдан')
```

Как сделать cooldown в python?

При вводе команды 'бонус' пользователю должно написать сообщение: Бонус выдан!
А при повторном вводе, 'Подождите ещё чч:мм:сс'. А если 5 минут прошли, то снова дать доступ к бонусу.

На PHP работает это:

```
                   elseif($body[0] == 'бонус' || $body[0] == 'Бонус'){
                        $from_id = $this->conf->data->object->from_id;
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '.$from_id;
    foreach ($db->query($sql) as $row) {
    }
   if(!$row['id']){
   $db->exec("INSERT INTO users VALUES ($from_id, 5000, null, null, null, null, null, null, null)");
   $db->exec("UPDATE users SET bonustime = '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."'"." WHERE id = $from_id");
   $this->send("$nick, \n\n✅Вы получили бонус в размере 2500$!");
   echo 'ok';
   continue;
}
if (!$row['bonustime']) {
    if($row['status'] == 'VIP'){
        $db->exec("UPDATE users SET balance = {$row['balance']} + 5000 WHERE id = $from_id");
        $this->send("$nick, \n\n✅Вы получили бонус в размере 5000$!");
        $db->exec("UPDATE users SET bonustime = '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."'"." WHERE id = $from_id");
        echo 'ok';
        continue;
    }
    $db->exec("UPDATE users SET balance = {$row['balance']} + 2500 WHERE id = $from_id");
    $this->send("$nick, \n\n✅Вы получили бонус в размере 2500$!");
    $db->exec("UPDATE users SET bonustime = '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."'"."WHERE id = $from_id");
} else {
    $ts = strtotime($row['bonustime']);
    $now = strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
  $time = $now - $ts;

  if($time <= 3600) {
     $self = "$nick, \n\n⌚️Ждите 1 час";
  } else {
      if($row['status'] == 'VIP'){
          $db->exec("UPDATE users SET balance = {$row['balance']} + 5000 WHERE id = $from_id");
          $this->send("$nick, \n\n✅Вы получили бонус в размере 5000$!");
          $db->exec("UPDATE users SET bonustime = '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."'"."WHERE id = $from_id");
          echo 'ok';
          continue;
      }
    $db->exec("UPDATE users SET balance = {$row['balance']} + 2500 WHERE id = $from_id");
    $this->send("$nick, \n\n✅Вы получили бонус в размере 2500$!");
    $db->exec("UPDATE users SET bonustime = '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."'"."WHERE id = $from_id");
  }
}
}
```

А как на питоне?

Answer (score 1):

Вот моё решение.

```
from time import sleep

def check_bonus(text, time):

    assert type(text) is list
    assert type(time) is int
    assert len(text) > 0
    while not text[0] == 'Бонус':
        print('Подождите ещё {} секунд'.format(time))
        sleep(time)
    print('Бонус выдан')


>>> check_bonus([''], 5)
Подождите ещё 5 секунд
Подождите ещё 5 секунд



>>> check_bonus(['Бонус'], 5)
Бонус выдан
```

***ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ***

Перечитав вопрос, понял, что нужно другое решение:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from time import sleep

first_call_time = datetime.now()
current_call_time = first_call_time


def check_bunus(text, seconds):

    assert type(text) is list
    assert type(seconds) is int
    assert len(text) > 0

    global first_call_time
    global current_call_time

    current_call_time = datetime.now()

    if text[0] == 'Бонус':
        if current_call_time > first_call_time:
            print('Бонус выдан')
            first_call_time = datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=seconds)
        else:
            cooldown = first_call_time - current_call_time
            print('Подождите ещё {}'.format(str(cooldown).split('.')[0]))
    else:
        # some logic
        pass


    check_bunus(['Бонус'], 5)
    check_bunus(['Бонус'], 5)
    sleep(5)
    check_bunus(['Бонус'], 5)
    check_bunus(['Бонус'], 5)
```

Comment: Такой же почти написал, но ты быстрее выложил

Comment: Мне нужно где-то хранить время, например в SQLITE, и отображать не только секунды, а остаток времени в формате чч:мм:сс

Comment: @АминАлиев, последний вариант, похоже, делает то, что тебе нужно, без SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

С сохранение времени:

```
from time import time
from datetime import datetime as dt


def savetosql():
    print(f'--->>>UserBonus {dt.now():%H:%M:%S}')


# время ожидания в секундах
waits = 300
# храним время получения бонуса, 0 - не получал еще
t = 0
while True:
    print('Enter text: ')
    usertxt = input()
    if usertxt == 'bonus':
        timeleft = time()-t
        if t == 0 or (timeleft == waits):
            t = time()
            savetosql()
        else:
            print(f'Wait, please {round((waits-timeleft)/60)} minutes')
```

Comment: Мне нужно где-то хранить время, например в SQLITE, и отображать не только секунды, а остаток времени в формате чч:мм:сс

Comment: хранить какое время? время получения бонуса или оставшееся?

Comment: Получения бонуса

Comment: смотрите код выше, он сохраняет время получения  бонуса.